# tsconfig property not working when using glob-like pattern

Tags: typescript

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "tests1"
},
"include": [
    "api/**/*spec.ts"

 ]}
```

Hi All!
 There is my tsconfig file I just want to compile only spec.ts files in specified directory but the result is that it compiles my full project files (ts)
Any ideas. I think that glob pattern is not working properly.

Comment: Your tsconfig file works fine when I test it myself. Which version of TypeScript are you using? Which operating system? How are you compiling this - just running "tsc" from the command line? Do you happen to have an IDE (Visual Studio Code, IntelliJ IDEA etc) open at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

> There is my tsconfig file I just want to compile only spec.ts files in specified directory but the result is that it compiles my full project files (ts)

Your tsconfig is fine. Update to latest TS and use the terminal / cmd to run it and it will work fine.